# Python script not run in Django environment

Tags: python, django, anaconda

Terminal says that i didn't defined DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE but i tried as i thought every method to do it and so far nothing helper (coding on windows)
Can someone help me out please? I am stuck and dont know what to do
Maby this will help - i run my virtual env through Anaconda -

```
conda activate djangoenv





raise ImproperlyConfigured(django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

```
from faker import Faker
from app.models import AccessRecrod, Webpage, Topic
import random
import django
import os

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')


django.setup()


fakegen = Faker()
topics = ['Search', 'Social', 'Marketplace', 'News', 'Games']


def add_topic():
    t = Topic.objects.get_or_create(top_name=random.choice(topics))[0]
    t.save()
    return t


def populate(N=5):

    for entry in range(N):

        # get topic for entry

        top = add_topic()

        # create fake data for entry

        fake_url = fakegen.url()
        fake_date = fakegen.date()
        fake_name = fakegen.company()

        # create new webpage entry

        webpg = Webpage.objects.get_or_create(
            topic=top, url=fake_url, name=fake_name)[0]

        # create fake access record

        acc_rec = AccessRecrod.objects.get_or_create(
            name=webpg, date=fake_date)[0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('populating script!')
    populate(20)
    print('populating complete!')
```

Comment: It's possible that your app models are accessing Django settings, and you import those before you set the value.  Move the `import os` and `os.environ.setdefault` lines to the very top, before any other imports.

Comment: What is the value of 'project.settings' in the bash? I think it should not be a string but executed. But from where is `project`?

Comment: project.settings is huge file with all basic settings of django

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim `'project.settings'` is correctly a string. The `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable should be a filename which contains Django settings.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice this is my full path to this python file - D:\projects\django_pierian_yt\project\project\settings.py

Comment: @user15481122 See my answer below for an alternative approach to do what you are trying to do here. Since you already have your code organized in functions here, you can turn it into a `Command` really easily.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i want to find out where is the problem in my code to understand how not to do in the future

Comment: @user15481122 IMO, the problem here is that you are not using the correct approach to begin with. While you can probably get things to work this way, it will be painful. The easier approach is to create a `Command` class as the link I gave in my answer describes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Problem is simply your import of models. You just need to setup django before you import anything related to django:

```
import django
import os

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')
django.setup()


from faker import Faker
from app.models import AccessRecrod, Webpage, Topic
import random

rest of your code
```

If you check the code in manage.py and django code on github you will essentially find the same sequence of code (besides a lot of additional stuff) when you run a management command by "python manage.py your_command"

To use the management command directly as described in the answer from @Code-Apprentice would be the other "normal" or "more django way" to integrate your script.

But you asked for the reason of the error message in your way of doing it.

If you study the complete error trace you will also find that it starts at the import command.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to shoe horn a regular python script into the Django environment like this, I suggest you create a command which you can run with `./manage.py`. You can learn how to create your own custom commands [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-management-commands/). When you do this correctly, you can run a command like `./manage.py create_topics` or whatever name you give your command. This allows `manage.py` to load the Django environment for you.

Alternatively, you could look at creating [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/initial-data/#providing-data-with-fixtures) with `./manage.py dumpdata` and `./manage.py loaddata`. These commands will allow you to create data and save them to a .json file which you can load into your database at any time.